# Function parameter by value vs reference memory managment

Tags: c, memory-management

I am trying to understand C language, more specifically about memory managment. I have a function `func` that takes 1 argument, an int pointer. If I used `int i` instead of `int *i` it would allocate more memory because the value would be copied. Since I know that both `func1` and `func2` will not change the `i` variable, the result of those 2 functions is exactly the same.

What would happen if I called those functions many times ? Obviously the `func1` would perform better, correct ? What about `func2` ? Would it allocate new memory every time it is called ? So allocate 10000 * 4 extra bytes ? or just 4 extra bytes ?

I suppose it allocates 4 extra bytes, if it actually is, when is this memory allocated ? Is it when the function is first called ? Also, how and when will this 4(?) bytes of memory become free ?

```
void func1(int *i)
{
}

void func2(int i)
{
}

void main()
{
    int x = 100;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000 ; i++) func1(&x);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000 ; i++) func2(x);
}
```

Comment: In a 64 bit machine `func1()` would require more space because it needs to copy the pointer which is `64` bits in size AFAIK.

Comment: in C, ALL arguments are passed by value,  because of that, all arguments are actually copies, so all arguments take up extra space (usually on the stack)  Now, that argument could be a pointer.  (A copy of a pointer still points to the same place.)   I have seen lots of beginning C programers that did not understand the above.  So the would change the parameters to a function and then be frustrated because the original value was not changed back in the calling function.   In most instances, a integer and a pointer are the same size, so take the same amount of room on the stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably compiler-specific (you could look through the C spec to be sure), but the integer parameter should be allocated on the call stack for the function. Each time you call the function, there will be an extra 4 bytes allocated to work with that will be freed when the function returns.

For the reference version of the function, it will allocate space for the int pointer on each function call. Depending on your machine, that may be bigger, smaller, or the same size as an int. Compare `sizeof(int)` with `sizeof(int*)` to see which is bigger.

Comment: On very common architectures (e.g. 32-bit ARM, x86-64) with common ABIs, the first few arguments are actually passed in registers.

Answer (score 2):

Let's talk about *storage duration,* which is the duration for which the object (region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values) named by a variable exists. Function arguments and local variables with no explicit storage duration or storage duration `auto` or `register` have *automatic storage duration.* That is, they are created when they are declared and are destroyed when the function containing them returns.

On function call the values specified for the arguments are copied into the automatic variables representing the arguments in the function definition. These variables are destroyed on function return so unless you recursively call yourself, you won't amass tons of memory. You shouldn't care about the difference between the size of an `int` and an `int*` either unless you have a lot of these. When in doubt, profile and change the code when it turns out that you have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard does not specify how arguments are passed, however, in most C implementations, the memory used by arguments are automatically allocated and freed on the call stack, which has little overhead compared to heap allocation. Usually, memory is allocated on the stack as the arguments are passed, and freed before or when the function returns.

Both versions of function will allocate memory on the call stack. The reference version will allocate memory for the pointer. And the reference version is probably slower because it involves pointer dereference.

Comment: is `func2(x)` slower than `func2(100)`  ?

Comment: @Shiro That depends on a lot of factors but generally you won't see any speed difference between these two. The compiler might be able to optimize `func2(100)` further than `func2(x)` because it knows the argument's value.

Answer (score 1):

As the risk of over simplification and looking at practicable implementation, there is generally no performance or memory difference between

```
void func1(int *i)
void func2(int i)
```

A compiler is going to implement the former something like

```
PUSHAL I(SP)
CALL   func1
```

and the latter like

```
PUSHL I(SP)
CALL func2
```

For atomic values, there simply is not going to be much difference. Change to

```
struct somestruct 
{
   char buffer [20000] ;
}  ;
```

In that case

void func3(somestruct *i)

is likely to be much faster than

void func3 (somestruct i)

because the amount of data to be copied is much greater.